# setting jqGrid data after the grid has been created

Tags: jqgrid

The following example code will load a jqGrid (this code works) ...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var gridData = [
                { col1: 'cell11', col2: 'cell12', col3: 'cell13' },
                { col1: 'cell21', col2: 'cell22', col3: 'cell23' }
                ];
    $('#myGrid').jqGrid({
        data: gridData,
        datatype: 'clientSide',
        colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'],
        colModel: [
                        { name: 'col1' },
                        { name: 'col2' },
                        { name: 'col3' }
                        ]
    })
```

How would I rewrite the example so the gridData is set after the jqGrid is created?  I tried this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var gridData = [
                { col1: 'cell11', col2: 'cell12', col3: 'cell13' },
                { col1: 'cell21', col2: 'cell22', col3: 'cell23' }
                ];
    $('#myGrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'clientSide',
        colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'],
        colModel: [
                        { name: 'col1' },
                        { name: 'col2' },
                        { name: 'col3' }
                        ]
    })


    $('#myGrid')[0].data = gridData;
```

However the above code doesn't work.  Can someone show me how please?

UPDATE:  I also tried this for my last line, but it didn't work either...

```
    $('#jqgrid-panel-contents').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: gridData});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe try reloading the grid afterwards?

```
 $('#jqgrid-panel-contents').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: gridData}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out and came back to answer my own question and found yours.  Thanks!

Comment: @John: I am not sure with the last version, but probably one need call `refreshIndex` after the update of `data` parameter (see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414774/problem-with-deleting-jqgrid-row-data-client-side/3415086#3415086). It can be that `relodGrid` do already all the work. Moreover you should include in items of `gridData` array `id` property or use `localReader` to define which column of grid can be interpret as the id. For example `localReader: {id:'col1'}`

Comment: this solution doesn't work, when the grid is loaded with different data in the same page, n number of times. The old data remains and the new data gets added to it. Because setGridParam uses jquery.extend internally.[Click to see more](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/triggerreloadgrid-not-work/)

Answer (score 0):

@infantDev If I understood good what you were trying to say: I think you have to do a GridUnload

```
$("#jqgrid-panel-contents").jqGrid('GridUnload');
```

before to add the new data

Answer (score 0):

Solution from [Ewan Heming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098189/1041046) (above) won't work with [Free JQGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid) (at least with version 4.15.2) when there is data loaded in the grid and you want to modify the data.

however following which was suggested by [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) (I can't remember where) will work and it will also set your grid pager to 1 in case your new data doesn't have that many pages.

```js
var gParams = $('#myGrid').jqGrid("getGridParam");
gParams.data = data;
$('#myGrid').trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}]);
```