# Search is not working with filter toolbar in JQGrid

Tags: search, jqgrid

I am facing issue while loaidng the data in JQGrid at a later stage in place of at the time of ceating grid. I am using filter toolbar for search.

following is the code I am using:

**Creating Grid**

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            colNames: [my col names],
            colModel: [my col model],
             jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                //records: "records",
                repeatitems: false
            },
            height: 300,
            viewrecords: true,
            gridComplete: this.onGridComplete,
            ondblClickRow: this.rowDblClick,
            onSelectRow: this.selectRow,
            headertitles: false,
            loadtext: "Loading...",
            sortable: true,
            altRows: true,
            loadonce: true,
            rowNum: 100,
            pager: '#pager',
            root: "rows",
            rowList: [100, 200, 300],
            pagination: true,
            ignoreCase: true 
        })
```

**Load data at later stage**

```
if(gridDataStr != "none") // gridDatStr has data 
        {
            grid.initialize(); // create the grid
            var myjsongrid = JSON.parse(gridDataStr);            
            grid.table[0].addJSONData(myjsongrid);  
            grid.table.jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json', data:myjsongrid}).trigger('reloadGrid');          
            if (myjsongrid["rows"].length > 1) 
            {
                grid.table.filterToolbar({
                    stringResult: true,
                    searchOnEnter: false
                    });
            }
        }
```

However if I load the same data at the time of creating the grid with datatype:json and using some valid url, searching is working well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `addJSONData` can not be used to work with the jqGrid having the 'local' datatype.

You can use `addRowData` and to use [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data) instead of `jsonReader` or set `data` parameter of jqGrid with respect of `setGridParam` method and then call `jQuery("#list")[0].refreshIndex()` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348540/jqgrid-reload-grid-partially-working/3348688#3348688)) and reload the grid.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, it is working with addRowData and localReader but causing performance issues. My grid would be running with as much as 6000 records.

Comment: @Saleemuddin Mewati: Do you insert the records in the loop or do this in one call of `addRowData`? The way way from the performance point of view is the usage of `data` parameter. Moreover I hope that you use local paging (`rowNum` value which is small enough to display all rows of the page on the monitor without have to use vertical scrolling).