# How to assign the data dynamically to jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Here is my code for creating the jqGrid

```
$("#ptDataGrid").jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'local',
                    data: arrSpecData,
                    colModel: colmod,
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10],
                    pager: '#ptPager',
                    gridview: true,
                    rownumbers: false,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    loadonce:false,
                    hidegrid: false,
                    autowidth: true,
                    caption: 'Crank Pin',
                    height: '100%',
                });
```

Then i ahve applied some filters on my data and created another array called **FilteredData**. Now i wanted to assign this new Data source to my grid. I have tried all the approaches i know. But  nothing worked. So, How can we assign the new data source to the jqGrid Dynamically? Please suggest some way to assign it.

```
                dataGrid.setGridParam({ data: filterdData });
                dataGrid[0].refreshIndex();  
                dataGrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Still the same result i am getting :(

**Workaround #1**:

```
 $('#divGrid').children().remove();
 $('#divGrid').html(' <table id="ptDataGrid" class="jqgriddata"><tr><td/></tr></table><div id="ptPager"></div> ');  

 createGrid(filterdData,true);
```

Comment: I don't know how you tested my suggestion. In the "UPDATED" part of my answer I appended the lint to the demo which work.

Comment: @Oleg, i have tried your approach also. But it didn't work as expected.It displayed the updated results and also the previous data.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong! It displays *only updated data*. Just repeat your experiments or look more carefully on my demo. You can save the html page, modify the data from `mydata1` and `mydata2` and see that it really work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first set new `data` with respect of `setGridParam` and then call `refreshIndex` method (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348688/315935)) to update the internally used `_index` parameter.

**UPDATED**: Click on the button "Change data" on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AssignLocalData.htm) to verify that the approach work.

Comment: your demo worked for me, but when i integrated with my code, it gave me the same old issue. I think, i am missing something in my code. I will check.

Comment: @Dinesh: You post only small fragments of the code which you use, so I can't you find the error. jqGrid internally use not more as setting `data` and call `refreshIndex`. So it's correct way. What is exactly not work in your grid? Your error can be in the `colModel` or in the data `arrSpecData` which you use. These are the most important parts of your question.