# Does jqGrid have an afterSort event or something similar?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to manipulate a local array based on the sort order in my jqGrid as I'm using row indexes to modifiy the local data array which stuffs up when the grid is sorted by an alternate column. I can see the jqGrid has an `onSortCol` event that fires after the header is clicked but before the sort but nothing called after the sort. I can't see anything in the documentation that I could hook into? Any ideas?

EDIT: Adding some code

This is the full extent of my jqGrid code:

```
$list.jqGrid({
    formatter: {
        currency: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$", suffix: "", defaultValue: '0.00' }
    },
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['Id',
    '<img src=\'Images/Global/alert.gif\' alt=\'Set As Favourite\' title=\'Set As Favourite\' />',
    'Delivery #', 'Pickup', 'From', 'Deliver', 'To', 'Destination',
    'Carrier', 'Vehicle', 'Load', 'IsSelected', 'Status','PickupResourceId','DeliverResourceId'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', index: 'ConsignmentId', width: 65, hidden: true },
        { name: 'Favourite', index: 'Favourite', width: 18, align: 'center' },
        { name: 'DeliveryNumber', index: 'DeliveryNumber', width: 65 },
        { name: 'Pickup', index: 'Pickup', width: 60, align: 'left', sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'd/M/Y' },
        { name: 'From', index: 'From', width: 85, formatter: 'rowHeight' },
        { name: 'Deliver', index: 'Deliver', width: 60, align: 'left', sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'd/M/Y' },
        { name: 'To', index: 'To', width: 85, align: 'left', formatter: 'rowHeight' },
        { name: 'Destination', index: 'Destination', align: 'left' },
        { name: 'Carrier', index: 'Carrier', width: 65, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'Vehicle', index: 'Vehicle', width: 65, align: 'left' },
        { name: 'Load', index: 'Load', align: 'left', formatter: 'rowHeight' },
        { name: 'IsSelected', index: 'IsSelected', width: 5, hidden: true },
        { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 5, hidden: true },
        { name: 'PickupResourceId', index: 'PickupResourceId', hidden:true},
        { name: 'DeliverResourceId', index: 'DeliverResourceId', hidden:true}
    ],

    altRows:true,
    altclass:'myAltRowClass',

    width: gridWidth,
    height: "100%",
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    page: $listpg.val(),
    cellLayout: 7,

    pager: '#dispatch-footer',
    rowNum: 10,
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: 'invid',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    multiselect: true,
    onPaging: function (pgButton) {
        $listpg.val($list.getGridParam('page'));
    },
    onCellSelect: function (rowId, colId, cellContent, e) {
        if (colId != 0 ) { //&& colId != 2
            hideMsgs();
            $list.jqGrid('resetSelection');
            $list.jqGrid('setSelection', rowId);

            rowIdx = ($(this).getGridParam('rowNum') * ($(this).getGridParam('page') - 1)) + (rowId - 1);
            rowWasRemoved = false;

            var cons = $list.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 1);
            loadDelivery({});
            eCargo.api.get('v1.00/delivery/' + cons, 0, loadDelivery,
                funcError('Unable to load Delivery', 5000, $jobEdit));
            $jobEdit.dialog('open');
            $jobEdit.block();
        }
        /*if (colId == 2) {
            var newImage = $list.getCell(rowId, colId) == '' ? exclIcon : '';
            $list.setCell(rowId, colId, newImage, "", "");
            $list.jqGrid('resetSelection', rowId);
        }*/
    },
    onSelectRow: function (rowid, status) {
        var ret = $list.jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
        if (status) {
            if (selectedIds.indexOf(ret.Id) == -1)
                selectedIds.push(ret.Id);
        }
        else {
            selectedIds.splice(selectedIds.indexOf(ret.Id), 1);
        }
        $gIds.val(selectedIds.join('|'));
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        var ids = $list.getDataIDs();
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            $list.setRowData(ids[i], false, { height: 40 });
        }
        $('#jqgh_cb').css('text-align', 'center');
    },
    gridComplete: function () {
        var ids = $list.getDataIDs();
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            //if late
            if (dates.compare(
                    new Date($list.jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'Deliver')).addDays(1),
                    $list.jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'Deliver'))
                && $list.jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'Status') !== 'DELIVERED') {
                //$list.find("#" + ids[i]).css({ color: 'red' });
            }
            if ($gIds.val() != '') {
                var ret = $list.jqGrid('getRowData', ids[i]);
                if (selectedIds.indexOf(ret.Id) > -1)
                    $list.jqGrid('setSelection', ids[i]);
            }
        }
        $('#jqgh_cb').css('text-align', 'center');
    },
    onSelectAll: function (aRowids, status) {
        hideMsgs();
        var ids = $list.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var ret = $list.jqGrid('getRowData', ids[i]);
            //setIsSelected(ret.InvoiceId, status);
            //$list.jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], 'IsSelected', status);
            if (status) {
                if ($.inArray(ret.Id, selectedIds) == -1)
                    selectedIds.push(ret.Id);
            }
            else
                selectedIds.splice(selectedIds.indexOf(ret.Id), 1);
        }
        $gIds.val(selectedIds.join('|'));
    }
})
.navGrid('#dispatch-footer', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });
```

Here is where the data is loaded into the grid and a formatting function for the json:

```
var consLoader = new Loader({
    $grid: $list,
    URL: 'v1.00/delivery',
    count: 20,
    Error: funcError('Unable to retrieve search consignments.', 5000, $(this)),
    SearchNotFound: funcSuccess('No consignments found.', 5000),
    GridBound: function () {
        this.$grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { page: $listpg.val() }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    },
    DetailsSuccess: function (rtn) {
        var ldr = this;
        ldr.bindGrid = true;
        $.EO_each(rtn, function (i, e) {
            ldr.list.push(formatConsignment(e));
        });
    }
});

function formatConsignment(cons) {
    var icon = '';
    if (cons.ReturnLiability)
        icon = retnIcon;
    if (cons.ConsignmentAttrs && cons.ConsignmentAttrs.match('PRIORITY'))
        icon = exclIcon; // exclIcon is favourite
    return {
        $raw: cons,
        Id: cons.ConsignmentId,
        Favourite: icon,
        DeliveryNumber: cons.ConsignmentNbr,
        From: cons.PickupResourceName.toProperCase(),
        Pickup: vortalDateTime(cons.PickupPlannedDepartureDate),
        To: cons.DeliverResourceName.toProperCase(),
        Deliver: vortalDateTime(cons.DeliverPlannedArrivalDate),
        Destination: eCargoAddress(cons.DeliverToAddress).toProperCase(),
        Carrier: cons.CarrierResourceName.toProperCase(),
        Vehicle: cons.Vehicle == undefined ? '' : cons.Vehicle.toProperCase(),
        Load: cons.Description.toProperCase(),
        Comments: cons.Comments ? cons.Comments : '',
        PickupResourceId: cons.PickupResourceId,
        DeliverResourceId: cons.DeliverResourceId,
        Status: cons.Status,
        IsSelected: false
    };
}
```

Here's some json for three records.

```
{"_type":"Consignments","_":[{"_type":"Consignment","Deleted":"N","NoOrder":"N","ConsignmentId":4166306,"ObjectTypeName":"CONSIGNMENT","ReadTimestamp":"2012-03-16 19:34:17.113","ConsignmentAuths":"ASSIGN_VEHICLE|CHANGE|CREATE_LEGS|DEASSIGN_VEHICLE|DELIVER|DISPATCH|MAKE_PRIORITY|NOTIFY|REMOVE_PRIORITY|SUBCONTRACT|VIEW|","ConsignmentAttrs":"JOBTYPE=Grocery|","Description":"Palleted: 750 KGS, 10.52 M3, 224 Cartons, 4 PAL, 4 Lifts","ConsignmentNbr":"0081604437","PickupActualDepartureDate":"16 Mar 2012 19:33:30","Status":"DISPATCHED","NextAction":"Confirm Delivery","Vehicle":"cfd","DeliverResourceId":23760,"CarrierResourceId":2255,"PickupResourceId":7320,"OwnerResourceId":7320,"DeliverResourceName":"PAK N SAVE GLEN INNES","CarrierResourceName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","PickupResourceName":"Griffins Foods - DC","OwnerResourceName":"Griffins Foods - DC","CarrierResourceShortName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","DeliverToAddress":{"_type":"DeliverToAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"182 APIRANA AVENUE","Suburb":"GLEN INNES","City":"AUCKLAND","Country":"NZ","RegionId":478,"RegionName":"AKE"}},"PickupAddress":{"_type":"PickupAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"113-3 Savill Drive","Suburb":"Otahuhu","City":"Auckland","Country":"New Zealand","RegionId":400,"RegionName":"South Akld"}},"PickupPlannedArrivalDate":{"_type":"PickupPlannedArrivalDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeZone":"UTC@@plus;12"}},"PickupPlannedDepartureDate":{"_type":"PickupPlannedDepartureDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeZone":"UTC@@plus;12"}},"DeliverPlannedArrivalDate":{"_type":"DeliverPlannedArrivalDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeValue":"99:99"}},"DeliverPlannedDepartureDate":{"_type":"DeliverPlannedDepartureDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012"}},"ConsignmentItems":{"_type":"ConsignmentItems","_":[{"_type":"ConsignmentItemHeader","Deleted":"N","ConsignmentItemId":94540510,"ConsignmentItem":{"_type":"ConsignmentItem","Deleted":"N","Item":{"_type":"Item","ItemId":97277,"ItemDesc":"Palleted","Weight":7500000,"WeightUomCode":"Kilograms","WeightUomId":594,"Volume":105200,"VolumeUomCode":"m³","VolumeUomId":615,"Qty1":2240000,"Qty1UomCode":"Cartons","Qty1UomId":766,"Qty2":40000,"Qty2UomCode":"Pallet","Qty2UomId":648,"Qty3":40000,"Qty3UomCode":"Lifts","Qty3UomId":733}}}]},"ConsignmentPartners":{"_type":"ConsignmentPartners","_":[{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45203410,"RoleId":5,"RoleCode":"OWNER","RoleName":"Owner","PartnerName":"Griffins Foods - DC","PartnerResourceId":7320,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"113-3 Savill Drive","Suburb":"Otahuhu","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":400,"RegionName":"South Akld"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45203411,"RoleId":1,"RoleCode":"CARRIER","RoleName":"Carrier","PartnerName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","PartnerResourceId":2255,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"71-77 Westney Rd","Suburb":"Mangere","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":261,"RegionName":"Auckland South"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45203412,"RoleId":6,"RoleCode":"PICKUP_POINT","RoleName":"Outwards Goods","PartnerName":"Griffins Foods - DC","PartnerResourceId":7320,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"113-3 Savill Drive","Suburb":"Otahuhu","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":400,"RegionName":"South Akld"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45203413,"RoleId":4,"RoleCode":"MGR_SPECTATOR_OUT","RoleName":"Manager Spectator Outwards Goods","PartnerName":"Griffins Foods Ltd","PartnerResourceId":3329,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"Hunua Road","Suburb":"Papakura","PostCode":"1733","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":261,"RegionName":"Auckland South"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45203414,"RoleId":11,"RoleCode":"DIVISION_MANAGER_OUT","RoleName":"Division Manager Outwards","PartnerName":"Griffins Foods Ltd","PartnerResourceId":3329,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"Hunua Road","Suburb":"Papakura","PostCode":"1733","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":261,"RegionName":"Auckland South"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45203415,"RoleId":3,"RoleCode":"DELIVERY_POINT","RoleName":"Inwards Goods","PartnerName":"Glen Innes Pak N Save","PartnerResourceId":23760,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"182 Apirana Avenue","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}}}]},"AutoGenerateItems":"N","OriginatingOrder":{"_type":"OriginatingOrder","Deleted":"N","OrderId":8944037,"SalesOrderNumber":"3977545","PurchaseOrderNumber":"3977545","OrderType":"order","Description":"Palleted: 515.2 KGS, 10.12 M3, 224 Cartons, 6 PAL, 6 Lifts","SourceSystemReference":"0081604437","SourceSystem":"GRIFFINS"},"PickupCarrierId":2255,"PickupCarrierName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","L1_ResidualSplitLoad":{"_type":"L1_ResidualSplitLoad","Deleted":"N","NoOrder":"N","AutoGenerateItems":"N"}},{"_type":"Consignment","Deleted":"N","NoOrder":"N","ConsignmentId":4167062,"ObjectTypeName":"CONSIGNMENT","ReadTimestamp":"2012-03-16 18:03:33.407","ConsignmentAuths":"ASSIGN_VEHICLE|CHANGE|CREATE_LEGS|DEASSIGN_VEHICLE|DELIVER|DISPATCH|MAKE_PRIORITY|NOTIFY|REMOVE_PRIORITY|SUBCONTRACT|VIEW|","ConsignmentAttrs":"JOBTYPE=Grocery|","Description":"Palleted: 153.91 KGS, 1.0124 M3, 54 Cartons, 1 PAL, 1 Lifts","ConsignmentNbr":"0081604564","PickupActualDepartureDate":"16 Mar 2012 18:03:28","Status":"DISPATCHED","NextAction":"Confirm Delivery","Vehicle":"cfd","DeliverResourceId":29305,"CarrierResourceId":2255,"PickupResourceId":7320,"OwnerResourceId":7320,"DeliverResourceName":"METRO NEW WORLD QUEEN STREET 616672","CarrierResourceName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","PickupResourceName":"Griffins Foods - DC","OwnerResourceName":"Griffins Foods - DC","CarrierResourceShortName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","DeliverToAddress":{"_type":"DeliverToAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"125 QUEEN STREET","Suburb":"AUCKLAND CENTRAL","City":"AUCKLAND","Country":"NZ","RegionId":454,"RegionName":"ACM"}},"PickupAddress":{"_type":"PickupAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"113-3 Savill Drive","Suburb":"Otahuhu","City":"Auckland","Country":"New Zealand","RegionId":400,"RegionName":"South Akld"}},"PickupPlannedArrivalDate":{"_type":"PickupPlannedArrivalDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeZone":"UTC@@plus;12"}},"PickupPlannedDepartureDate":{"_type":"PickupPlannedDepartureDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeZone":"UTC@@plus;12"}},"DeliverPlannedArrivalDate":{"_type":"DeliverPlannedArrivalDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeValue":"08:00"}},"DeliverPlannedDepartureDate":{"_type":"DeliverPlannedDepartureDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeValue":"08:00"}},"ConsignmentItems":{"_type":"ConsignmentItems","_":[{"_type":"ConsignmentItemHeader","Deleted":"N","ConsignmentItemId":94557821,"ConsignmentItem":{"_type":"ConsignmentItem","Deleted":"N","Item":{"_type":"Item","ItemId":97277,"ItemDesc":"Palleted","Weight":1539100,"WeightUomCode":"Kilograms","WeightUomId":594,"Volume":10124,"VolumeUomCode":"m³","VolumeUomId":615,"Qty1":540000,"Qty1UomCode":"Cartons","Qty1UomId":766,"Qty2":10000,"Qty2UomCode":"Pallet","Qty2UomId":648,"Qty3":10000,"Qty3UomCode":"Lifts","Qty3UomId":733}}}]},"ConsignmentPartners":{"_type":"ConsignmentPartners","_":[{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45200146,"RoleId":5,"RoleCode":"OWNER","RoleName":"Owner","PartnerName":"Griffins Foods - DC","PartnerResourceId":7320,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"113-3 Savill Drive","Suburb":"Otahuhu","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":400,"RegionName":"South Akld"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45200147,"RoleId":1,"RoleCode":"CARRIER","RoleName":"Carrier","PartnerName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","PartnerResourceId":2255,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"71-77 Westney Rd","Suburb":"Mangere","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":261,"RegionName":"Auckland South"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45200148,"RoleId":6,"RoleCode":"PICKUP_POINT","RoleName":"Outwards Goods","PartnerName":"Griffins Foods - DC","PartnerResourceId":7320,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"113-3 Savill Drive","Suburb":"Otahuhu","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":400,"RegionName":"South Akld"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45200149,"RoleId":4,"RoleCode":"MGR_SPECTATOR_OUT","RoleName":"Manager Spectator Outwards Goods","PartnerName":"Griffins Foods Ltd","PartnerResourceId":3329,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"Hunua Road","Suburb":"Papakura","PostCode":"1733","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":261,"RegionName":"Auckland South"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45200150,"RoleId":11,"RoleCode":"DIVISION_MANAGER_OUT","RoleName":"Division Manager Outwards","PartnerName":"Griffins Foods Ltd","PartnerResourceId":3329,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"Hunua Road","Suburb":"Papakura","PostCode":"1733","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":261,"RegionName":"Auckland South"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45200151,"RoleId":3,"RoleCode":"DELIVERY_POINT","RoleName":"Inwards Goods","PartnerName":"METRO NEW WORLD QUEEN STREET 616672","PartnerResourceId":29305,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"125 QUEEN STREET","Suburb":"AUCKLAND CENTRAL","City":"AUCKLAND","Country":"NZ","RegionId":454,"RegionName":"ACM"}}}]},"AutoGenerateItems":"N","OriginatingOrder":{"_type":"OriginatingOrder","Deleted":"N","OrderId":8945604,"SalesOrderNumber":"3978056","PurchaseOrderNumber":"3978056","OrderType":"order","Description":"Palleted: 136.91 KGS, 1.047 M3, 64 Cartons, 1 PAL, 1 Lifts","SourceSystemReference":"0081604564","SourceSystem":"GRIFFINS"},"PickupCarrierId":2255,"PickupCarrierName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","L1_ResidualSplitLoad":{"_type":"L1_ResidualSplitLoad","Deleted":"N","NoOrder":"N","AutoGenerateItems":"N"}},{"_type":"Consignment","Deleted":"N","NoOrder":"N","ConsignmentId":4167304,"ObjectTypeName":"CONSIGNMENT","ReadTimestamp":"2012-03-16 15:39:10.247","ConsignmentAuths":"ASSIGN_VEHICLE|CHANGE|CREATE_LEGS|DEASSIGN_VEHICLE|DELIVER|DISPATCH|MAKE_PRIORITY|NOTIFY|REMOVE_PRIORITY|SUBCONTRACT|VIEW|","Description":"Palleted Goods: 1765 KG, 5.81 M3, 4 CARTONS, 4 CHEP","ConsignmentNbr":"PZC-01298521","PickupActualArrivalDate":"16 Mar 2012 00:00:00","PickupActualDepartureDate":"16 Mar 2012 00:00:00","ProtectionType":"Ambient","Status":"DISPATCHED","NextAction":"Confirm Delivery","Vehicle":"cfd","DeliverResourceId":23773,"CarrierResourceId":23103,"PickupResourceId":29069,"OwnerResourceId":29061,"DeliverResourceName":"Mt Albert Pak N Save","CarrierResourceName":"Route and Retail","PickupResourceName":"PZ Cussons Auckland","OwnerResourceName":"PZ Cussons (NZ) Pty Ltd","DeliverToAddress":{"_type":"DeliverToAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"1167-1177 New North Road","City":"MT ALBERT","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}},"PickupAddress":{"_type":"PickupAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"EX Mondiale AKL","Suburb":"78 Montogomerie Road, Airport Oaks","City":"Auckland","RegionId":284,"RegionName":"Auckland"}},"PickupPlannedArrivalDate":{"_type":"PickupPlannedArrivalDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"16 Mar 2012","TimeValue":"14:30"}},"PickupPlannedDepartureDate":{"_type":"PickupPlannedDepartureDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"16 Mar 2012","TimeValue":"14:30"}},"DeliverPlannedArrivalDate":{"_type":"DeliverPlannedArrivalDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeValue":"17:00"}},"DeliverPlannedDepartureDate":{"_type":"DeliverPlannedDepartureDate","VortalDateTime":{"_type":"VortalDateTime","DateValue":"19 Mar 2012","TimeValue":"17:00"}},"ConsignmentItems":{"_type":"ConsignmentItems","_":[{"_type":"ConsignmentItemHeader","Deleted":"N","ConsignmentItemId":94550141,"ConsignmentItem":{"_type":"ConsignmentItem","Deleted":"N","Item":{"_type":"Item","ItemId":2321559,"ItemDesc":"Palleted Goods","Weight":17650000,"WeightUomCode":"Kilogram","WeightUomId":593,"Volume":58100,"VolumeUomCode":"m³","VolumeUomId":615,"Qty1":40000,"Qty1UomCode":"Cartons","Qty1UomId":766,"Qty2":40000,"Qty2UomCode":"Chep","Qty2UomId":723}}}]},"ConsignmentPartners":{"_type":"ConsignmentPartners","_":[{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190257,"RoleId":6,"RoleCode":"PICKUP_POINT","RoleName":"Outwards Goods","PartnerName":"PZ Cussons Auckland","PartnerResourceId":29069,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"EX Mondiale AKL","Suburb":"78 Montogomerie Road, Airport Oaks","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":284,"RegionName":"Auckland"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190258,"RoleId":11,"RoleCode":"DIVISION_MANAGER_OUT","RoleName":"Division Manager Outwards","PartnerName":"Foodstuffs Inbound","PartnerResourceId":23095,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"Kiln Street","Suburb":"Silversteam","City":"Wellington","Country":"NZ","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190259,"RoleId":11,"RoleCode":"DIVISION_MANAGER_OUT","RoleName":"Division Manager Outwards","PartnerName":"FIN Account Managers","PartnerResourceId":27078,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Country":"NZ","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190260,"RoleId":3,"RoleCode":"DELIVERY_POINT","RoleName":"Inwards Goods","PartnerName":"Mt Albert Pak N Save","PartnerResourceId":23773,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"1167-1177 New North Road","Suburb":"Mt Albert","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190261,"RoleId":17,"RoleCode":"LOGISTICS_PROV","RoleName":"Logistics Provider","PartnerName":"Foodstuffs Inbound","PartnerResourceId":23095,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"Kiln Street","Suburb":"Silversteam","City":"Wellington","Country":"NZ","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190262,"RoleId":5,"RoleCode":"OWNER","RoleName":"Owner","PartnerName":"PZ Cussons (NZ) Pty Ltd","PartnerResourceId":29061,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"Building C4","Suburb":"Pacific Road, Mt Wellington","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190263,"RoleId":1,"RoleCode":"CARRIER","RoleName":"Carrier","PartnerName":"Route and Retail","PartnerResourceId":23103,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"3 Roma Road, Mt Roskill","Suburb":"DX Box CX 15021","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190264,"RoleId":2,"RoleCode":"CARRIER_SPECTATOR","RoleName":"Carrier Spectator","PartnerName":"Foodstuffs Inbound","PartnerResourceId":23095,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"Kiln Street","Suburb":"Silversteam","City":"Wellington","Country":"NZ","RegionId":2,"RegionName":"New Zealand"}}},{"_type":"ConsignmentPartner","Deleted":"N","PartnerId":45190265,"RoleId":1,"RoleCode":"CARRIER","RoleName":"Carrier","PartnerName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","PartnerResourceId":2255,"PartnerAddress":{"_type":"PartnerAddress","Address":{"_type":"Address","Street":"71-77 Westney Rd","Suburb":"Mangere","City":"Auckland","Country":"NZ","RegionId":261,"RegionName":"Auckland South"}}}]},"AutoGenerateItems":"N","OriginatingOrder":{"_type":"OriginatingOrder","Deleted":"N","OrderId":8946047,"PurchaseOrderNumber":"138807","OrderType":"order","Description":"Foodstuffs Consignment","SourceSystem":"CMP"},"PickupCarrierId":2255,"PickupCarrierName":"Cardinal Logistics Ltd","L1_ResidualSplitLoad":{"_type":"L1_ResidualSplitLoad","Deleted":"N","NoOrder":"N","AutoGenerateItems":"N"}}]}
```

Note I upgraded to jqGrid 4.3.2 but that had no effect. Let me know if posting the Loader code would help but it's really only a call to our api to pull back the json and set some properties to bind the data to the grid/handle errors.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `loadComplete` as "afterSort" event. It is really good place for such actions. If needed you can set some variable inside of `onSortCol` event and test it and then reset it inside of `loadComplete`. In the way you will be able to distinguish reloading of the grid because of changing sort order from reloading of the grid because of other reasons.

By the way jqGrid has internally row indexes. It's `_index`. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026210/315935) for example for additional information. Moreover you can use [getLocalRow](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L3494-3505) method of jqGrid which get you reference to the item in the `data` by rowid. If needed you can modify any property of the object returned by [getLocalRow](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.2/js/grid.base.js#L3494-3505) method.

**UPDATED**: From the email which you sent me I know that you set `data` parameter of jqGrid with respect of `setGridParam` method after loading of the data from the server. In the case you have to rebuild another internal jqGrid parameter `_index` by calling of `refreshIndex` method. The method is expando of table DOM, the corresponding call looks like `$("#grid")[0].refreshIndex()`.

In the most cases the `_index` will be rebuild automatically, but in your case it is undefined. So I think that manual rebuilding of `_index` using `refreshIndex` method should solve your problem.

I recommend you to rebuild `_index` after setting of `data` and *before* reloading of the grid using `.trigger("reloadGrid")`.

You can find more about the usage of `refreshIndex` method in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9002088/315935).

Comment: $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index') is returning undefined.

Comment: $list.jqGrid('getLocalRow', rowId) is returning false also - I've tried it in the onCellSelect when I have a rowId but also in my other functions and have tried hardcoding a 'valid' index number. I'm definately using datatype = 'local' btw.

Comment: $list.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data') is returning my data.

Comment: @lloydphillips: You should include the code which you use. It can be that you fill jqGrid in wrong way. The best would be if you post also test data (at least one line) which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @lloydphillips: One more important question: Which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: I've updated the post with the code. Note I've also upgraded to 4.3.2 but that's had no effect.

Comment: @lloydphillips: You current code contains `datatype: "local"`, but no `data` parameter. JSON data which you posted looks like data returned from server by some separate Ajax request. why you do so? Moreover your code don't contain filling of the grid which seems me the main your problem. Many places of your code make it slow or very slow. The code of `loadComplete` and `gridComplete` looks like the bottleneck. All the remarks are far from your main question: the usage of `loadComplete` as "afterSort" event.

Comment: The data is populated in the Loader. We break up our data because we can be dealing with thousands of records and the users need the data up immediately so we break up the requests and trickle the data into the grid. I know there's a way of demand loading when you page etc but it's not my call. Any thoughts on the actual question and where you think I should go from here? Seems even more inefficient to have to iterate the data after a sort to check which record I need or reorganise it every time a sort happens.

Comment: @lloydphillips: Sorry, but I can't follow you. You wrote "The data is populated in the Loader." What do you mean. I can't understand the code `var consLoader = new Loader(...);` too. I see no code which shows **how you fill jqGrid with data ?**. You current code in `loadComplete` uses `setRowData` inside of loop. Every change of one element on the page follows to [reflow](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html) of **the whole page** which is expansive (see [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)). If you need set `height: 40` on every row you can use CSS.

Comment: I can't add the Loader code, it's saying I've got over 30k characters in the post if I try. :s

Comment: I'll try to remove the setRowData from the loop. We originally had to use it to highlight rows (orders to be dispatched) in red that were 'late' but that code was taken out a few weeks back (with the intention of putting it back when that feature is needed). We had problems with setting height via CSS from recollection but I can't recall why. Not sure how I can show you this Loader code.

Comment: @lloydphillips: How you communicate with the server? Do you make `$.ajax` call to the server? How many rows the grid typically has (10, 100, 1000, 10000)? I asked: "how you **fill** jqGrid with data?". Do you use `addRowData` in the loop? Do you use `addJSONData`? Do you set `data` parameter and call `.trigger("reloadGrid")`? Depend on how you fill grid the callbackes `loadComplete` or `gridComplete` could not called at all. I am sure that one do can `height: 40` of every row using CSS. Any other changes of rows styles you can do using `rowattr`. It's many time effectively.

Answer (score 2):

It uses jQuery-UI sortable which includes a sort stop event. You can listen on it with,

```
$('#jqgrid').on( "sortstop", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

I didn't test this so I'm not certain which element in the grid you will need to listen on.

Comment: I tried `$(document).on('sortstop', '*', function(event, ui) {});` and the event never fired, so it must be using some internal element that's not attached to the DOM.